# What does the `effect` mean in `scalaz-effect`

Tags: scala, functional-programming, effects, scalaz

I see `scalaz` has a module `scalaz-effect`:

> scalaz-effect: Data structures to represent and compose IO effects in the type system.

I'm not quite sure what does `effect` means here. Is it a special concept? Or just the `effect` in `side-effect`?

Comment: more generally scalaz effect provides a way to encapsulate stateful computations

Comment: It's pretty much just the effect in side effect. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effects and side effects are different things.

Effects are pure expressions that describe interactions with the outside world, but do not actually perform that interactions. Therefore, effects are *referentially transparent*. For example, `IO.putStrLn("Hello, world")` is an effect.

Side effects are observable interactions with the outside world, which are happening when the interpreter run effects. For example, to make our `IO` example perform side effects, we should run the method `unsafePerformIO` on it:

```
IO.putStrLn("Hello, world").unsafePerformIO()
```

Without `unsafePerformIO` our expression of type `IO[Unit]` is just a pure expression (like `5 + 8` or `"abc"`).